# Why is git stash removing my node_modules folder?

Tags: git, gitignore, node-modules, git-stash

I'm having an issue where when I run `git stash -u` (ie. stash all, including untracked files), Git removes my node_modules directory. On top of this, it doesn't even restore it on `git stash pop` - I have to run `npm install` again to get it back.

node_modules is ignored in .gitignore (via the line `node_modules/*`), and as far as I can see has never been committed in the history of the project (`git log --all -- node_modules` returns nothing). Shouldn't `git stash` ignore it (even when committing untracked files)? I'm pretty sure I've used `git stash` like this before without any issues with node_modules.

**Update:** I've checked, and this issue is not limited to a particular project - it seems to happen anywhere I run `git stash -u`. For what it's worth, my Git version is 2.6.3.windows.1 (on Windows).

Comment: No problem for me. It seems not the problem in git. You might try it on others' machine, and see if it happens?

Comment: Are you using the same version of Git as me?

Comment: No. But I guess it doesn't have anything to do with the version of Git. Saeed's answer below might have the right direction.

Comment: Hmm, it seems a little hasty to assume it's nothing to do with the version of Git, given that (a) it's something that probably shouldn't be happening (ie. I don't think it's expected behaviour for `git stash`) and (b) it's something that didn't used to happen (on my machine).

Comment: I've got similar problem on my machine. When I use `git stash -u` it removes all of my NuGet packages, even though I have `**/packages/*` in my `.gitignore`. My git version is 2.8.4.windows.1.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your `.gitignore` entry from:

```
node_modules/*
```

to

```
node_modules/
```

More details here: [Git Stash Can Delete Ignored Files (git stash -u)](http://blog.icefusion.co.uk/git-stash-can-delete-ignored-files-git-stash-u/)

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me - even without the asterisk, `git stash -u` still deletes the node_modules folder.

Answer (score -1):

npm creates very long paths, which can exceed the 260 character max on Windows, depending on how long the path of your repo root is.  This could explain why you sometimes see that it works and other times not.  If you're using npm, I suggest making sure that your repos always have a very short root path.

Comment: I think this used to be true for npm 2, but npm 3 puts all sub-dependencies in the top-level node_modules folder, so you no longer tend to get the massive nesting that used to happen. Also, in my experience, this tended to cause Windows to be *unable* to delete `node_modules`, whereas the problem I'm having is the opposite. Besides, I can't see why npm's paths would specifically cause a problem with Git stash. Especially when node_modules is gitignored anyway...